# Управление checkbox'ом в listView. JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx, checkbox

Добрый день.
Начал изучать JavaFX. Не могу разобраться как можно убирать/добавлять признак selected с чекбоксов в listView, на текущий момент могу только получить, то что выбрал пользователь. Вот кусок кода, который использовался

```
listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
        BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) ->
                        System.out.println("CheckBox для " + item + " изменен с " + wasSelected + " в " + isNowSelected)
        );
        return observable;
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, чем вы параметризовываете свой список, должен содержать признак того, что айтем выбран или нет. Вот простой пример, который демонстрирует данное поведение.

```
ListView < MyItem > listView = new ListView < > ();
listView.setCellFactory(p - > new ListCell < MyItem > () {
    private CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null && !empty) {
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                item.setSelected(newValue);
                System.out.println("CheckBox для " + item + " изменен с " + oldValue + " в " + newValue);
            });
            checkBox.setText(item.getView());
            setGraphic(checkBox);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
});
```

и сам класс MyItem

```
public class MyItem {
    private String view;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public MyItem(String view) {
        this(view, false);
    }

    public MyItem(String view, boolean isSelected) {
        this.view = view;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```